# encoding an url string if it contans the following string

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, url

I am using the code like

```
searchQuery =  [searchQuery stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://google.com/#auto|en|%@", searchQuery];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

The code is run when I pressed a button app not open the browser, if I remove the last phrase "#auto|en|" it is working fine. How I can encode the string to give an url.

Comment: Have you tried printing the resulting `urlString` to the console (with `NSLog(@"urlString: %@", urlString)` and seeing what you actually have?

Answer (score 0):

check the searchQuery it is not accepting your any parameters like this.. or give more description so other people can give proper response on it.